# Class 'XSLTProcessor' not found

Tags: apache, php, dll, xslt

Никак не могу подключить использование XSLT на localhost.
В php-файле при создании экземпляра класса

```
$xsl = new XSLTProcessor();
```

выдаёт ошибку:

```
Class 'XSLTProcessor' not found
```

При этом php_xsl.dll размещена в \usr\local\php5\ext\ (стоит Denwer, Версия PHP - 5.3.3, windows 7); в php.ini всё разрешено:

```
extension=php_xsl.dll
```

Перепробовал, кажется, все возможные варианты - всё равно не работает. Вероятно, чего-то всё же не учёл. В чём может быть проблема? И - в windows/system32/ должны быть размещены копии .dll или нет?

---

**UPD:**
Внезапно пришла в голову идея проверить дату выпуска php_xsl.dll. Оказалось, что библиотека очень старая, скорее всего, была создана ДО выхода версии 5 PHP.
Скачал новую. Разместил в директории с расширениями. Однако apache при запуске утверждает, что:

> PHP Startup: unable to load dynamic
> library
> ‘/user/local/php5/ext/php_xsl.dll’

...хотя она там, конечно же, есть. 
Что сие может означать? Что библиотека битая? Сдаётся мне, что проблема в чём-то другом...
и ещё, если это существенно, также сообщает:

> Точка входа в процедуру xmlNewDocPI не
> найдена в библиотеке libxml2.dll

Comment: сервер перезапускали?

Answer (score 1):

**Первый способ:**

1) Посмотрите значение директивы **Configuration File (php.ini) Path** в информации, которую выдаст функция phpinfo() и забросьте нужный dll в этот каталог. Перезапустите Денвер.

2) В этом случае строчка в php.ini должна выглядеть так:

```
extension=php_xsl.dll
```

**Второй способ:**

1) Проверьте значение директивы **Loaded Configuration File** в информации выведенной посредством функции phpinfo(). Там должен быть указан путь к файлу, который используется при загрузке интерпретатора PHP.

2) В файле, который указан в значении директивы **Loaded Configuration File** пропишите абсолютный адрес к php_xsl.dll. Так как Denwer устанавливается в какое-то место на вашем диске (например C:/Program Files/Denwer), то строчка подключения php_xsl.dll в php.ini в этом случае должна выглядеть примерно так:

Пример:

```
extension=c:/program files/denwer/usr/local/ext/php5/php_xsl.dll
```

3) Перезапустите Денвер.

Answer (score 1):

В интернете масса советов о том, как "поправить" php.ini, чтобы всё заработало, однако в действительности проблема несколько сложнее. Главным образом из-за того, что далеко не всякая .dll подходит к конкретной версии Windows, установленной на компьютере, о чём мало кто упоминает.
В данном случае причина заключалась именно в этом. Найти нужную версию php_xsl.dll (как и другие библиотеки) можно здесь: http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/
Об этом хорошо написано в этой статье: http://webhybrid.ru/prog/php/xslt-processor.
Но вот чего там не написано, так это того, как выяснить, какая из предлагаемых библиотек, действительно, подойдёт. Для моей 5.3 версии php, в частности, предлагалось целых 9 вариантов:

```
•   php-5.3.3-nts-Win32-VC6-x86.msi
•   php-5.3.3-nts-Win32-VC6-x86.zip
•   php-5.3.3-nts-Win32-VC9-x86.msi
•   php-5.3.3-nts-Win32-VC9-x86.zip
•   php-5.3.3-src.zip
•   php-5.3.3-Win32-VC6-x86.msi
•   php-5.3.3-Win32-VC6-x86.zip
•   php-5.3.3-Win32-VC9-x86.msi
•   php-5.3.3-Win32-VC9-x86.zip
```

Давайте разберёмся, какой из них выбрать, проанализировав названия.
php-5.3.3 - тут всё понятно

```
•   Win32 - подойдёт и 32-х, и к 64-х разрядной версии
•   VC-6/9 - версия компилятора Windows для PHP.
```

Последний параметр можно узнать из phpinfo.php сервера (если у вас стоит Denwer - http://localhost/phpinfo.php). См. параметр "PHP Extension Build" или "Zend Extension Build".
После того, как нужный вариант скачан, откройте папку ext в полученном архиве и скопируйте библиотеки в директорию Apache. 
Далее всё, как обычно - проверить php.ini, перезапустить сервер.
Надеюсь поможет всем, кто столкнулся с подобной проблемой.